# How to find and replace line only once when found multiple times in Python

Tags: python, replace, find

I have three lists: filePath, textToFind, textToReplace.  I need to open each file at the given filePath, find a line and replace a line.  The lists are always in order and always the same length.  Here the code:

```
for i, path in enumerate(filePath):
   for line in fileinput.input(path, inplace=1):
      sys.stdout.write(line.replace(textToFind[i], textToReplace[i]))
```

The problem is that textToFind can be found numerous times in the file and so this code replaces all occurrences of the text it finds with the current index position of textToReplace.  I need it to break when it finds the item the first time and then move on to the next iteration.  How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want to replace file at each index of `filePath` with corresponding index entries in `textToFind ` and `textToFind `? OR, all the entries of `textToFind` with `textToFind` in all the files present in `filePath`?

Comment: The first.  I want to replace each index of filePath with the corresponding index in textToFind and textToReplace.  filePath and textToFind is not always unique but textToReplace is always unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to detect when there's something to replace. If found, flag, but continue writing the rest of the lines or you'll truncate the file.

(note that using `zip` on the 3 lists avoids carrying the index)

```
for path,find,replace in zip(filePath,textToFind,textToReplace):    
   match_found = False
   for line in fileinput.input(path, inplace=1):
      if match_found:
         # keep writing the rest of lines, unchanged
         sys.stdout.write(line)
      else:
         # try to replace
         rep = line.replace(find, replace)
         sys.stdout.write(rep)
         if line!=rep:
             # flag: don't replace anything till the end
             match_found = True
```

EDIT: after a small discussion with the author of another answer, I think his 2 loops pattern is better than 1 with a flag, so I borrowed it, saves the need for the flag, must be slightly faster:

```
for path,find,replace in zip(filePath,textToFind,textToReplace):
   handle = fileinput.input(path, inplace=1)
   for line in handle:
     rep = line.replace(find, replace)
     sys.stdout.write(rep)
     if line!=rep:
        break
   for line in handle:
      sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution has significantly been reduced in elegance. However I still feel like offering an alternative with a temporary file.

```
# loop over every path, thing to find and replacement in the lists
for path, needle, replacement in zip(filePath, textToFind, textToReplace):
   with open(path) as read_handle:
       with open(path + '.tmp', 'w+') as write_handle:
            # first print and replace
            for line in read_handle:
                 write_handle.write(line.replace(needle, replacement))

                 # if we found something
                 if needle in line:
                     break # quit this the inner for-loop

            # the remaining lines should be printed without modification
            for line in read_handle:
                  write_handle.write(line)
    # overwrite the file with the temporary file
    shutil.move(path + '.tmp', path)
```

Comment: that's not writing back in the file

Comment: I like your elegant way of not using a flag, just break first replacement loop and simply iterate to the end. I'll edit your answer so it answers the question.

Comment: actually the `fileinput.input` uses a temporary file. So your solution is good as well (I had to look up the `fileinput` module). I borrowed you the double `for` loop as it is better.

Answer (score 1):

As an answers to your actual question:

> *"How to find and replace line only once when found multiple times in Python"*.

[`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) has a optional `maxreplace` option that limits the number of occurrence to be replaced. As per the [document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace):

> **string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace])**:
>
> Return a copy of string s with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. *If the optional argument maxreplace is given, the first maxreplace occurrences are replaced.*

For example:

```
>>> my_test_string = 'Hello Hello Hello'

#                                            v  maxreplace as `1`
>>> my_test_string.replace('Hello', 'World', 1)
'World Hello Hello'
# ^ Only first word is replaced
```